# JSP importing java class in Openshift

Tags: java, jsp, openshift, jsp-tags

I made a java web project in Eclipse and it works great (with jsp, servlets, and java classes). Now I'm trying to make it live. I decided to host it on Openshift which provides its own file structure. I've tried copying my files over and it works for the most part.

The problem is my import tags don't seem to work and it doesn't find my classes (such as databaseInteractor which fetches information from my database to be displayed). This might be a path issue but I'm not sure.

This is what I had in Eclipse that was working:

```
<%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import ="databaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor" %>
<%@ page import ="databeseInteractor.House" %>
```

In Eclipse I had both my classes House.java and DatabaseInteractor.java in the databaseInteractor package. But in OpenShift I don't understand what is the equivalent of a package.

I've tried various iterations of the path and errors I've gotten were:

1. Only a type can be imported. MyClasses.DatabaseInteractor resolves to a package 
   \(where MyClasses was a folder I made in OpenShift)
2. DatabaseInteractor cannot be resolved to a type

As you can see below, I've copied DatabseInteractor everywhere for purposes of debugging. What would you suggest I try in my import tags?

[image: This is what my file structure looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking at your question more, there are lots of issues going on.  Packages on OpenShift work exactly like packages do in Java anywhere else.  If your project is working locally, i am surprised, it must be due to some Eclipse magic with class paths.

1.)  All .java files should be in your src/main/java directory, that way they get compiled into classes etc (assuming this is a maven based project structure, which it looks like it is).

2.)  Any java class that is in a package should be INSIDE of a folder that is named the same as the package, for instance, `databaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor` should be in the location `/src/main/java/databaseInteractor/DatabaseInteractor.java`, the same with any other class that is part of a package.

3.)  `<%@ page import ="databeseInteractor.House" %>`, database is spelled incorrectly, which may be causing some issues.

4.)  Also, it's hard to tell on there, but your web.xml file should be inside of the WEB-INF folder, but not inside of that "package" folder.
I would suggest that you research how to use packages in Java, and also spend some time researching java web projects that use a Maven structure.

Comment: I cloned the git repo to my local machine and am editing it here. I then use command line to add/commit/push. The changes then display at the url (at least for html, jsp, images, css). Should that work or would you recommend trying it differently?

Comment: What does the top of your DatabaseInteractor.java file look like? (from the top down to (and including) the class name)?

Comment: good point, I hadn't thought to look inside the java file. The first line looks like this: package databaseInteractor; What package should it have instead? How exactly do packages work in openShift?

Comment: thank you corey112358! your first insight worked. It was broken because the first line of my java file had "package databaseInteractor;" and I had no such package in my OpenShift file structure. Its working great now.